# Passing session value to silverlight through WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, xaml, session

i Have a Session in asp.net page with a value assigned to it, now i need to access that session value from silverlight xaml.cs page, how to do that, both silverlight and web application are in same solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i thought to do is ,in the xaml.cs page i want to query the data on a condition that the data to  query should be the data of the user id stored in the session,but later what i did is ,in the WCF file i created i did the following,

at the beggining i checked if web.config file has aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"

```
<system.serviceModel>

        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
            multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    </system.serviceModel>
```

in Services1.cs file i wrote the code like below

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServices1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<TableName> GetList();
    }
```

then in IServices1.svc.cs file i wrote the following code

```
 public class Services1 : IServices1
    {


        public List<TableName> GetList()
        {
            //the below sess variable stores the user id value,based on which the query
            // executes
            int sess = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["User"]);
            DreamDataContext Data = new DreamDataContext();
            var value = from s in Data.TableNames where s.To == sess select s;
            return value.ToList();
        }



    }
```

now i accessed the above code in MainPage.xaml.cs page as shown below

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ServiceReference1.Services1Client webservice = new Services1Client();
            webservice.GetListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetListCompletedEventArgs>(webservice_GetListCompleted);

            webservice.GetListAsync();

        }


        public void webservice_GetListCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetListCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Attached the data to the DataGrid in silverlight
            DataGridImages.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
```

what i learnt is for the people who are new to WCF if they want to access data based on the session value this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

add follwoing settings in web.config and access session from HttpContext

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />    
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Update**
set session variable in WCF service as below

```
  HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = value;
```

and access this variable in silverlight as below

```
var value=HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"];
```

Comment: it is enabled ,should i store the session value to a variable in WCF file using HttpContext ? but i am unable to do that, can you please write a code

Comment: iam unable to add system.web namespace to xaml.cs page to access HttpContext